# Apparently nondeterministic behavior in this code calling out to an external process

Tags: c#, git, powershell, process, msbuild

We have the following class in some infrastructure code. It is part of an MSBuild task which I usually execute from PowerShell. All Git commands are available to me in my PowerShell environment; this is not a Git problem.

```
public class Git
{
    public static string GetCurrentBranch()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to find current Git branch...");
        string branch = null;
        /* git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD */
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("git", "rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        var process = new Process();
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => { branch += args.Data; };
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => { branch += args.Data; };
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit(5000); // Potential failure point?
        Console.WriteLine("Git branch set to '{0}'", branch);
        return branch;
    }
}
```

Most of the time I see it writing output like this:

```
 Trying to find current Git branch...
 Git branch set to 'feature-multitenancy-steel-thread'
```

However, on occassion—and to my chagrin, I have not been able to figure out a pattern in when this happens—I get output like this:

```
Trying to find current Git branch...
Git branch set to ''
```

and this when I am definitely in a Git repository and `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` is definitely returning a branch name if I execute it directly. I wondered if maybe the `WaitForExit()` call wasn't waiting long enough and it was exiting before setting the branch, but when it fails it doesn't seem to take five seconds, and I've never observe the `rev-parse` command to take that long anyway.

Because I am unable to reproduce this situation consistently, I was wondering if it was obvious from the code whether we are using `Process` wrong or something. Any C#/.NET gurus who can punch holes in this code?

Comment: You mention the output (i.e. the variable `branch`) does not have the expected value. More importantly: was the git operation actually performed. If the answer is "yes", then you know you did not wait long enough. If the answer is "No" you may need to do some troubleshooting.

Comment: You have to check return code of the process, after it finishes. On success, git.exe returns 0, when it fails it returns non-zero code. From my experiment, launching this command line in directory without repository I get 128.

Comment: @S.T. Thanks. I've added diagnostics for that. We'll see what I can learn.